# how can know database name in oracle web logic server

Tags: oracle, weblogic

I'm using oracle web logic server. How can I find out the database name and port number?

Comment: As I understand from your comment below, you know the place where you can provide the DB name and port in WLS but you don't know the DB name:port to use, then this is something you need to check with your DBA, this can't be answered in this forum.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the name of the Database at runtime? for Example from within a EJB.. or CID Bean?

Comment: @ SridharS ⇒　yes,how can check my DBA, As I didn't have experience in using WLS. So please!

Comment: @StefanHeimberg ⇒ yes, yes, I want to get the name of the Database at runtime. How can know?

Comment: i will try it myself... but i think it could be possible to get the the information somewhere on a jdbc connection or some where else... but i think that all this would be proprietary to weblogic / jdbc driver etc..

Answer (score 1):

You can use nslookup or tnsping to know the host name and port of the database.

```
nslookup DATABASE_SID

tnsping DATABASE_SID
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can login to the console and navigate to Data Sources (for WLS10 and above)  and click the available data source and click the tab Connection Pool. You would need to navigate to the tab Connection Pool if WLS 8 is being used.

[image]

2) Alternatively you can go to the weblogic domain of your instance and check in the config directory , $WLS_DOMAIN/config/jdbc and view the contents of the datasource's xml file.

Comment: ⇒no no, I know that place to give database name. Now, i don't know database name.                                                                            eg. Database Name:   SampleName                                                                  I want to know really database name instead of SampleName.